# How do I take each token of a Scanner input iteratively?

Tags: java

I have an input from scanner. I would like to take each token with a while-loop.

Here's what I've tried:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(sc.hasNext()){
      String s = sc.next();
      //do stuff with String s
}
```

The code above always results in an infinite loop.

Comment: Are you actually getting the expected values assigned to string ```s``` ?

Comment: When are you expecting it to stop? `System.in` can always have more. You could define some `if (“q”.equals(s)) { break; }` condition to just exit when the user sends ‘q’.

Comment: `Scanner#hasNext()` will wait a new type in. Need set a termination, like: terminated with char `#`.

Comment: You use `command+d` in MacOS(maybe `CTRL+d`for linux) to interrupt the `System.in` loop, and continue the following process.